# Breaking up a fixed length flat file into fields

Tags: vb.net, file, parsing, streamreader, flat

so i have a file that i need to read in vb.net.  Each line is 32 chars long and each line consists of multiple fields.  Meaning from char 1 to 9 it idicates ID then char 10 indicates an identifier,11-14 indicates a value field.  I've looked at Readblock and it's not the tool for the job.  Is there a way to break up each line into its respective fields other than just reading the whole line and breaking it up as a string?

Comment: VB has no `scanf` equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading it in and breaking it up is probably the simplest solution. If this is a one-off job, or if you don't expect the string format to change, then going with the simplest, quickest route is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to work with substring ... there is no way for .net to "know" what a string means or if he consists of fields (exception: if there is a fixed length string WITH field terminator chars ...)

Answer (score 0):

does each line has seperators for the fields ? If there is use a tokenizer to split the line into fields, if there is not just use a substring for each field i.e substr(line,1,5) for first field, substr(line, 6, 20) for field 2 and so on

Comment: no separators, just a fixed width.  Substring seems to be the play here.